# How to merge two list of dictionaries based on a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries, lets say:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'city': 'b'}]
```

I want to have a list that merges every dictionary in both lists with the same ID. In this example i expect to have:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'b'}]
```

Is there any cleaner way of doing it other than a for nested into the other?

Thanks

Comment: what should happen if two dictionaries have same keys (except the id key)?

Comment: Only one key per dictionary? Are these the best examples to show? Perhaps if you actually showed what you coded as a solution all would become clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep track of the ids with another dict (or defaultdict to make things simpler). Then update the items in that dict as you iterate. In the end the dict's values will have your list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)

a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'a'}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'city': 'b'}, {'id': 2, 'city': 'c'}, {'id': 3, 'city': 'd'}]

for item in a + b:
    d[item['id']].update(item)
list(d.values())

# [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'b'},
#  {'id': 3, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'd'},
#  {'id': 2, 'city': 'c'}]
```

Note this will overwrite duplicate values other than id — so if you have two with `id: 1` and two different cities, you will only get the last city.

Comment: Thats perfect. Thanks!!

One more thing, if i want to add a default value, like 'NoName' if one of the keys doesnt exist, lets say, 

a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'a'},  {'id': 4, 'name': 'a'}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'city': 'b'}, {'id': 2, 'city': 'c'}, {'id': 3, 'city': 'd'}]

If i want the list to be:
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'b'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'd'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'NoName'}, {'id': 2, 'city': 'c', 'name': 'NoName'}]

Any pretty way other than checking in d if the key exists and if not, add it?

Comment: JaviDR - I’m out and typing on my phone so I can’t easily post code, but you could use something like  defaultdict(lambda: {your defaults here}) to generate a populated dict as the default.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to make a dictionary, mapping the identifier that you want to use (id in this case) to a dictionary of merged results.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import collections

def merge_on_key(list_of_dictionaries, key, result):
    for d in list_of_dictionaries:
        assert(key in d)
        result[d[key]].update(d)

a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'city': 'b'}, {'id': 2, 'color': 'blue'}]

print 'a', a
print 'b', b

c = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {})
merge_on_key(a, 'id', c)
merge_on_key(b, 'id', c)

print 'merged results in dictionary with id 1', c[1]
```

That returns:

```
merged results in dictionary with id 1 {'city': 'b', 'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}
```

Comment: question states having lists of dictionaries and not just two dictionaries

Comment: whoops! let me try and see if I can update sensibly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`, `lambda` function in conjunction with `update` method for dictionaries, like this:

```
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'k'}]
b = [{'id': 1, 'city': 'b'}, {'id': 2, 'city': 'c'},  {'id': 4, 'city': 'cm'}]
a.extend(list(map(lambda x,y: y if x.get('id') != y.get('id') else x.update(y), a, b)))
a = list(filter(None, a))
```

`a` will now become a list containing dictionaries of merged values like this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'b'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'c'},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'k'},
 {'id': 4, 'city': 'cm'}]
```

Comment: For that to work you have to assume that `a[0].id == b[0].id`, which might not always be the case.

Comment: Also, would you mind adding an explanation of what your code does? Remember that you are writing answers for a wide audience, and including _why_ this solution works makes your answer so much better.

Comment: I also want it to add any item that is in b and not in a. For example:
a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}]
b = [{'id': 2, 'city': 'b'}, {'id': 1, 'city': 'c'}]

Should have a = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a', 'city': 'c'}, {'id': 2, 'city': 'b'} ]

Comment: Okay, I have added that to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
l1 =[{'id': 1, 'City': 'Calcutta'}, {'id': 3, 'Country': 'Germany'}]
l2 = [{'id': 1, 'Country': 'India'}, {'id': 2, 'City': 'Delhi'}, {'id': 3, 'City': 'Berlin'}]

def merge1(l1,l2):
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for l in (l1, l2):
        for innerdict1 in l:
            d[innerdict1['id']].update(innerdict1)

    l4 = sorted(d.values(), key=itemgetter("id"))
    l4p = print(l4)
    return l4p
merge1(l1, l2)

"""
[{'id': 1, 'City': 'Delhi', 'Country': 'India'}, {'id': 2, 'City': 'Calcutta'}, {'id': 3, 'Country': 'Germany', 'City': 'Berlin'}]

"""
```