# Django Combine Common Values from Joining Two List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, merge

I have 2 Lists of dictionaries, example below:

```
list one = [
  {'day': '2021-09-05 00:00:00+02:00', 'airtime_total_for_day': '650.00', 'data_total_for_day': '0'},
  {'day': '2021-09-16 00:00:00+02:00', 'airtime_total_for_day': '124.20', 'data_total_for_day': '20.00'},
]

list_two = [
  {'day': '2021-09-10 00:00:00+02:00', 'data_bundle_total_for_day': '100.00'},
  {'day': '2021-09-16 00:00:00+02:00', 'data_bundle_total_for_day': '50.00'},
  {'day': '2021-09-18 00:00:00+02:00', 'data_bundle_total_for_day': '45.00'},
]
```

I would like to merge the two lists together and at the same time, merge `data_total_for_day` with `data_bundle_total_for_day` under the name `data_total_for_day`.

Also, if `data_total_for_day` & `data_bundle_total_for_day` happen to fall on the same day which they do on the `2021-09-16`, the values need to be added together *e.g.*

- `data_total_for_day` on the `2021-09-16` is: `20.00`
- `data_bundle_total_for_day` on the `2021-09-16` is: `50.00`

So on that *specific* day, `data_total_for_day` needs to be: `70.00`

I've struggled and all & any help with be greatly appreciated.

Things I tried:

- https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/merge+two+list+of+dictionaries+python
- [How to merge two list of dictionaries based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863590/how-to-merge-two-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-a-value)
- [join two lists of dictionaries on a single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501810/join-two-lists-of-dictionaries-on-a-single-key)

Comment: How are these lists being generated? Are they the result of calling `values()` on two querysets?

Comment: @IainShelvington this is generated in django. I created a query using the ORM.

Comment: It's probably possible to do this by combining your queries into one. Can you add your model(s) and queries to the question?

Comment: hi @IainShelvington unfortunately I can't do that :(, it's for a client & he/she says I can't do that. Privacy issue.

Comment: Understandable, even an obfuscated example? Your totals appear to be strings which could cause issues, unless parsing them needs to be part of the solution?